# Pronúncia da palavra "ruim"

Tags: pronúncia

Qual seria a pronúncia correta da palavra "ruim"? Melhor dizendo, qual é a sílaba tônica ("rú-im" ou "ru-ím")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A palavra "ruim" é oxítona, portanto, 2ª opção: "ru-ím".

Comment: Se fosse oxítona seria Rúim, Segundo o [Separador de Sílabas](http://www.separarensilabas.com/index-pt.php) ru-im (2 sílabas)

Comment: acho que você está confundindo "monossílabo" com oxítona...

Comment: É, foi um lapso justo, pois pensei na primeira opção formando um ditongo "ruim" como algumas pessoas pronunciam, ou seja, tudo junto. Dessa forma, para melhorar a resposta deveria indicar a separação silábica correta

Answer (score 3):

Em pt-BR, a pronúncia de "ruim" varia não apenas de região para região, mas também em um mesmo local.  Mais comumente encontramos aqueles que pronunciam a palavra como tendo duas sílabas mas, até mesmo entre membros de uma mesma família, há aqueles que optam por pronunciá-la com apenas uma sílaba. Eu mesmo, carioca da gema, costumo pronunciar "ruim" como tendo duas sílabas, sendo "im" a sílaba tônica. Mas, ocasionalmente, também pronuncio da outra forma, com a palavra tendo apenas uma sílaba (e um ditongo), principalmente quando se trata da gíria "é ruim, hein".

Comment: Tenho um dificuldade muito grande em identificar as variantes. Não consegues arranjar exemplos audíveis?

Comment: Concordo. Embora pela norma culta a palavra "ruim" seja oxítona, dependendo do ambiente esta pronúncia pode parecer afetada, pedante, ou simplesmente estranha.

Comment: A pronúncia ru-ím é a formal, e dou exemplo lógico "muita coisa ruim acontece quando se fala desse jeito", percebe-se que é mais fácil a pronúncia da vogal "a" seguinte a palavra "ruim" quando pronunciado o "ruim" como hiato do que quando pronunciado como ditongo.

Answer (score 2):

É possível verificar as **duas pronúncias na linguagem informal**. Como a palavra "ruim" tem duas sílabas e não é acentuada, deve ser pronunciada (em linguagem formal) como oxítona: "**ru-ím**".

- Você pode verificar o **significado e a sílaba tônica de qualquer palavra** neste ótimo dicionário online: [https://dicionario.priberam.org/](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fixe).
- Você pode verificar a **pronúncia de palavras na voz de nativos** da língua portuguesa aqui: https://forvo.com/pronounce/